# How should I version control my JavaFx 8 project in git repository with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, javafx, javafx-8, gitignore

I have created a JavaFX project in a git repository and I've added a `.gitignore` file with eclipse specific files (I don't want to mix the eclipse project files with code).

But if I don't add the eclipse project files to the repository, then I can't import the JavaFX project in eclipse after eclipse project files are gone (e.g. after a hard reset or cloning the repository to another machine etc.)

How should I version control my code without version controllig the eclipse project files?
How should I import the Java FX project into eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I version control my code without version controlling the eclipse project files?

Here is the list of entries to add to your `.gitignore` file:

```
.metadata
local.properties
.settings/
# Eclipse Core
.project

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# JDT-specific (Eclipse Java Development Tools)
.classpath

# Java annotation processor (APT)
.factorypath
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the problem is not with my .gitignore file. I use the linked file's content, what contains all file formats you have mentioned: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore

I think, the problem is that the eclipse doesn't know that it's a javafx project I want to import.